# sql.limit on the number of related tables

Tags: sql

I need to select a table that have one join table

for example there are tables:

```
Role,AccountRole,Account
AccountRole - many to many relationship
```

need to select role, which has one account

```
Role table
id  name 
1   admin 
2   user 
3   external 

Account table
id  name 
1   homer 
2   jessica 
3   simpson 

AccountRole table
account_id role_id 
1          1 
1          2 
2          2 
3          3
```

query:

```
SELECT  role.id    
FROM    Role role
        INNER JOIN AccountRole accRole
            ON accRole.role_id = role.id

        INNER JOIN Account acc
            ON accRole.account_id = acc.id

GROUP BY role.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

in the query result:

```
role.id 
2 
3
```

but I need role.id which role.name = "external"(in this instance role.id = 3,but not 2)

how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID    -- change this to the original name of your Role Column
FROM    Role a
        INNER JOIN AccountRole b
            ON a.RoleID = b.RoleID -- an assumption that their linking
                                   -- column name is RoleID
        INNER JOIN Account c
            ON b.AccountID = c.AccountID -- an assumption that their linking
                                         -- column name is AccountID
GROUP BY a.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: what condition do you want?

Comment: example:where c.name = 'account1'.
but if I add this condition, result set have roles, which has more than one account

Comment: @MaksiK can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: it works for this query, but not on the actual query:
`select worker.id
from Worker worker
inner join account acc on worker.account_id = acc.id
inner join account_role accountRole on acc.id = accountRole.account_id
inner join role on accountRole.role_id = role.id
inner join role_action on role.id = role_action.role_actions_id
inner join action act on role_action.action_id = act.id AND  act.code = 'external'
group by  worker.id
having count(*) = 1` 

what is wrong here